# App doesn't work in some localizations(eg. DE & FR) and works on others(eg. PT & Simplified Chinese)

Tags: android, locale

I'm developing an Android app in Eclipse with Android-2.1 as the "minimum".

The app works perfectly in default language (English). I decided to add multi localization, and the problem starts there.

I've created the strings.xml exactly like the english one (copy&paste) and then edited the new one replacing the english sentences with the new language sentences, putting it on the respective values folder (eg. values-de or values-de-DE (tried both) for Deutsch).

I've done this for multiple languages (Portuguese, Deutsch, French, Simplified Chinese).

The app itself changes a couple of textviews to some number values after pressing a button.

In English, Portuguese and Simplified Chinese, works like a charm.
In Deutsch and French, half the code inside the onClick isn't "read", but the debugger doesn't complain any errors.

If it's working in some languages, i think the problem probably has to do with something related to the localization configuration, but after googling i've found multiple tutorials doing exactly the same as i did.

Any ideas?

(Sorry for the long text and title, but i am having dificulties explaining the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually figured out.

It has to do with decimal values.
In USA/UK you use "." to refer as a decimal point.
In Germany/France you use "," to refer as a decimal point.

So the app simply couldn't comply with the values stated because of the differences in math representation.